# Pandas Multiply 2D by 1D Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Looking for an elegant way to multiply a 2D dataframe by a 1D series where the indices and column names align

df1 =

| Index | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 3 | 7 |
| 4 | 4 | 8 |

df2 =

|  | Coef |
| --- | --- |
| A | 10 |
| B | 100 |

Something like...

> df3 = df1.mul(df2)

To get :

| Index | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 500 |
| 2 | 20 | 600 |
| 3 | 30 | 700 |
| 4 | 40 | 800 |

Comment: unstack `df2` before multiplying

Comment: @sammywemmy or rather slice as Series ;)

Comment: that'd be nice; I think you should add that as an answer @mozway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as 1D DataFrame, you need to slice as Series to have 1D, then [`multiply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) (by default on `axis=1`):

```
df3 = df1.mul(df2['Coef'])
```

Output:

```
    A    B
1  10  500
2  20  600
3  30  700
4  40  800
```

If Index is a column:

```
df3 = df1.mul(df2['Coef']).combine_first(df1)[df1.columns]
```

Output:

```
   Index     A      B
0    1.0  10.0  500.0
1    2.0  20.0  600.0
2    3.0  30.0  700.0
3    4.0  40.0  800.0
```

Comment: @Scott `df[['Coef']]` is 2D, just with one dimension of length 1 ;)

Comment: Point taken.  df[['Coef']].ndim does return 2.